# GIOChannel sometimes it reads sometimes not

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, glib, uart

Here is piece of my code. I will explain the problem right after.

```
GIOStatus ret;
GError *err = NULL;
gchar *msg;
gsize *len;
ret = g_io_channel_read_chars (koncentrator, &msg, 13, &len, err);
printf ("Read %u bytes: %hx\n", len, msg);
```

My device sends chains of 13 bytes over the serial port. Unfortunately only first two bytes are read correctly. Maybe this is because only first two bytes can be interpreted as ASCII characters, this would be strange because I set the encoding as NULL with the function `g_io_channel_set_encoding(koncentrator, NULL, NULL);`

If I try to access the bytes after first two I get `Segmentation fault`, which is also strange because variable `ret` after reading contains `13` which means it had read 13 bytes.

I tryed to use `g_io_channel_read_line` and `g_io_channel_read_to_end`. With those two the program stucks at infinite loop (even when I verify the condition `G_IO_STATUS_EOF`).

The last problem, and maybe the most annoying is that it doesn't work at first time, I need to open the serial port with the terminal, like `cutecom` for example. Otherwise I can send the data but it doesn't detect any callback. I am sure of it because the device has diodes to indicate states of `RX` and `TX`.

I have no idea what is wrong, I will be very greatfull for giving me some tips or links to the suitable example. I feel like there is nothing more on google I could find. Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with serial ports you **must** configure them properly before starting to read. My guess is `cutecom` is setting some vital serial parameter, making the port usable. In other words the code you posted is not the problem. The missing code is.

A good way to check this is by using `stty`. This is just an example: use `man stty` to have the (admittely long) list of options.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 raw 9600 -parity
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. I would also like to ask how to make it pernament, should I add this to the boot rc script so that he would execute this after each boot?

Comment: @Marek Yes, e.g. you can use `/etc/rc.local`. A better approach would be to spawn the `stty` call at beginning of your program, via `g_spawn_command_line_sync()` for instance. The best solution would be to directly call the `termios` APIs to get the same configuration but this would involve much more work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature of `g_io_channel_read_chars` as per the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-IO-Channels.html):

```
GIOStatus           g_io_channel_read_chars             (GIOChannel *channel,
                                                         gchar *buf,
                                                         gsize count,
                                                         gsize *bytes_read,
                                                         GError **error);
```

You are passing `&msg` as the argument `buf`, thus you are passing a value of type `gchar**` where the function expects `gchar*`. You should pass `msg` instead. You should also first allocate the memory as it is the caller's responsibility and not the function's.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I added `malloc` and changed `&msg` for `msg` and this solved the problem with `Segmentation fault`.

But I still have the problem with comunication, I need to open the device with `cutecom` terminal and only then my C program will be able to receive messages from the device.

I forgot to say that I add the module to the kernel so I am sure the device exist in the system, it is note added by the `cutecom` terminal.